# Can we send object into data using fcm-node push notification

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
let messages = {
        
        registration_ids: tokenId,

        notification: {
          title: 'WebServer',
          body: 'Message from center'
        },

        data: { result: { type: 'add', data : 'New Record' }, sender: {'first_name': 'James', 'last_name': 'Antony' } },
      };

      fcm.send(messages, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          return err
          console.log("Something has gone wrong!", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response.results);
         
        }
      });
```

Can we send object inside data i.e result can supply type and message.

If I put inside object it does not send notification but if I do toString() it does work but at mobile end it shows [object][object].

How can we Make it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` node can only contain string values. It cannot contain more complex values, such as objects.

If you want to send more complex data, encode it as a string in your message, and decode that string in your application code. For example, you can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to send JSON objects.